# localization of date expressionson axis

Tags: python, altair

I try to display a timeaxis on a altair time series plot as localized months. I set localed to the appropriate code, but october still appears as oct and not as Okt.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import locale
from altair_saver import save

file = '.\lagebericht.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')

source = df
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_CH")

base = alt.Chart(source, title='Neumeldungen BS').encode(
    alt.X('test_datum:T', axis=alt.Axis(title="",format="%b %y"))
    )

bar = base.mark_bar(width = 1).encode(
    alt.Y('faelle_bs:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title="Anzahl Fälle"))
    )

line =  base.mark_line(color='blue').encode(
    y='faelle_Total:Q')

chart1 = (bar + line).properties(width=600)

base = alt.Chart(source, title='Meldungen kumulativ BS').encode(
    alt.X('test_datum:T', axis=alt.Axis(title="",format="%b %y"))
    )
line =  base.mark_line(color='blue').encode(
    alt.Y('faelle_bs_kum:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title="Anzahl Fälle"))
    )
            
chart2 = (line).properties(width=600)
save(chart1 & chart2, r"images\figs.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altair bridges Python and javascript; when you use the Python `locale` package, it only affects the locale in Python. What you need to do is change the locale for the javascript display. You can do this via the renderer `embedOptions` using `formatLocale` (see https://github.com/d3/d3-format/tree/master/locale) and `timeFormatLocale` (see https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/tree/master/locale)

Here's how you can set a DE locale for Altair rendering using the locale settings available at those links:

```python
import altair as alt
from urllib import request
import json

# fetch & enable a German format & timeFormat locales.
with request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-format/master/locale/de-DE.json') as f:
  de_format = json.load(f)
with request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-time-format/master/locale/de-DE.json') as f:
  de_time_format = json.load(f)
alt.renderers.set_embed_options(formatLocale=de_format, timeFormatLocale=de_time_format)
```